# Parsing file and sort lines by property

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, collections

So basically someone gave me a text file for me to read through Java and I have to print out certain parts of it.

So what I did was I put all of the text file into a `String` and between every word there's a `":"`. So i split all of the text with `":"` using `split` function. At first every line looks like this

```
firstName:Surname:Age:Country
firstName:Surname:Age:Country
firstName:Surname:Age:Country
firstName:Surname:Age:Country
firstName:Surname:Age:Country
firstName:Surname:Age:Country
firstName:Surname:Age:Country
firstName:Surname:Age:Country
```

After it would be the same thing without the colons.

So now if I say `all[0]`, I would get **all** the `firstNames` **only**.

What I'm trying to get is get the **top 3 highest ages** but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: [PerlMonks posted an example of a Schwartzian Transform in java.](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=264648)

Also worth looking at the general definition of a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

It sorts on items other than the obvious keys, modified with any necessary additional embedded logic.

Comment: “So now if i say all[0]…” And did you try an array index other than zero?

Comment: Do you want to get the whole line or just the age values?

Comment: You could, by the time you read the line, process the second index as an Integer and store it in a desired order. Then, afterwards, you just retrieve the first three.

Comment: @wleao i want to get the three highest age numbers

Comment: @wleao i also need to use a compartor.

Comment: Can you show us your current code? I'd like to see how you currently structured the data in your code, then we can easily adapt it to the sorting part. The procedure should be simple, read all data in something like `List<DataTriple>` and then sort it using a comparator that compares the age, for example the one returned by `Comparator.comparing(DataTriple::getAge)`. If efficiency matters you can also do **partial sort** since you are only interested in the top 3. For example by inserting everything in a `PriorityQueue` and then calling `poll` three times.

Comment: Im afraid i cannot do that. but i just need to know how to split and ascend/ descend a string with a couple of words.

Comment: i use a while loop to put the text file into an array. Which i named "all[]".

Comment: @PaulHodges sorry thats too hard for me to understand T - T.

Comment: @zabuza your making every line a string and the split it , however  i created 1 array that put aline in every array. so if i called the array all, and printed all[0], i would get the names of all the lines.

Comment: So you have an array `List<String>[]` with four elements? `all[0]` is a list of all first names, `all[1]` surnames, `all[2]` age and `all[3]` country? Please clarify and explain what you have in more detail. Also why do you want to use this approach? Don't you like mine approach? In my opinion it is far more readable, modular and easy to maintain. I mean it groups what belongs together.

Comment: 1. yeah thats how it works it takes the word of all the sentences which in  our case is names. 2. i know how to make it work but our teacher want us to use comparators and do it that way. also  what is path file= Paths.get(...)

Comment: to use paths and other  functions, do i need any imports?

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Suppose you have a file with lines like

```
John:Doe:20:USA
Jane:Doe:35:Germany
Robert:Moe:14:Japan
Larry:Loe:25:China
Richard:Roe:27:India
```

and you want the 3 lines with the highest age, that would be

```
Jane:Doe:35:Germany
Richard:Roe:27:India
Larry:Loe:25:China
```

The procedure is straightforward. First read all lines, split by `:` and parse the data into a wrapper class like `Person`. Collect them into some collection like `List<Person>` and sort them using a `Comparator` that compares the age. Alternatively you could let `Person` implement `Comparable` and then use their natural order.

If efficiency matters you can also do **partial sort** since you are only interested in the top 3 hits. For this you could use a `PriorityQueue`, insert all elements and call `poll` three times.

---

### Solution

First the `Person` wrapper class

```
public class Person {
    private String mFirstName;
    private String mSurname;
    private int mAge;
    private String mCountry;

    public Person(String firstName, String surname, int age, String country) {
        this.mFirstName = firstName;
        this.mSurname = surname;
        this.mAge = age;
        this.mCountry = country;
    }

    // TODO Some getters

    public String toString() {
        return this.mFirstName + ":" + this.mSurname
            + ":" + this.mAge + ":" + this.mCountry;
    }

    public static Person parse(String[] data) {
        String firstName = data[0];
        String surname = data[1];
        int age = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
        String country = data[3];

        return new Person(firstName, surname, age, country);
    }
}
```

Next we read all lines, split the data and parse them into `Person`. After that we sort and limit the result to `3`. Finally we collect to a `List` and print the results.

```
Path file = Paths.get(...);
Pattern separator = Pattern.compile(":");

List<Person> persons = Files.lines(file) // Stream<String>
    .map(separator::splitAsStream)       // Stream<String[]>
    .map(Person::parse)                  // Stream<Person>
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed())
    .limit(3)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

persons.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or if you want to use the `PriorityQueue` as suggested, which will improve runtime:

```
Path file = Paths.get(...);
Pattern separator = Pattern.compile(":");

PriorityQueue<Person> personQueue = Files.lines(file)
    .map(separator::splitAsStream)
    .map(Person::parse)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> {
        return new PriorityQueue<>(
            Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed());
    }));

List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>(3);
persons.add(personQueue.poll());
persons.add(personQueue.poll());
persons.add(personQueue.poll());

persons.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: +1 for a detailed answer, but I thought OP wanted the top 3 highest ages right? thus maybe we need to do `Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge).reversed()` rather than `Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge)`. Also, it would be better to use `Comparator.comparingInt` to avoid boxing.

Comment: @Aominè Yes, good advice. Didn't knew the later method, thanks.

Comment: what imports did you use for this code, and what does the "Path file = Paths.get(...);" mean.

Comment: @Anwarkhan As I use an IDE the imports are automatically created. However there should be no ambiguous class, everything is of the standard library, you should have no problems finding the correct paths on your own. `Path file = Paths.get(...)` is the modern way of getting a reference to a *file* (the old way of using `new File(...)` is legacy). So for `...` you will substitute the path to the file, like `"dir/otherDir/file.txt"`, take a look at the **documentation**.

Comment: is there some sort of other way i can send you my code becasue its really hard and its due in two days time.

Comment: after your wrapper class i tried adding what you did. but Path file = Paths.get\(...) did not work.

Comment: @Anwarkhan What does "did not work" mean? Add the path to the file like `Paths.get("directory/otherDirectory/myFile.txt");` and import `Paths` correctly. Therefore, if you don't use an IDE, google it and the first result is its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html). There it lists the package as `java.nio.file.Paths`.

Comment: public class Task1  {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
     private Scanner x;
     public void openFile(){
         try{
             x = new Scanner(new File("shark-data.txt"));
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Error");
         }
     }    `this is how i put the text in to my code

Comment: @Anwarkhan Yeah, as said, reading with `File` and `Scanner` is **legacy**. You should do it by using `Paths.get(...)` and then using the methods of `Files`. However you can do whatever you like, you may go ahead and adapt my code to a `Scanner` version. If you have trouble with that please create a **new question** where you also show your **specific code** and explain your difficulties. You may then leave a link to the follow-up question here.